# How to check if custom ROM supports encryption?

Tags: custom-roms, encryption

First solution which is coming to my mind is install custom ROM and encrypt `/data` partition. But it always take time. I'm wondering if there's quicker method like download custom ROM, extract system image, then extract files from system image file and looking for encryption support in system files like `*.rc` which are in root file system. Is there any other way to checking?

Comment: FDE/FBE is almost a ready-made solution from AOSP. OEMs and ROM developers usually don't disable it. You can look into logs why the encryption fails. E.g. one reason could be if the filesystem created on `userdata` partition doesn't leave space for crypto footer.

Comment: @IrfanLatif maybe it's TWRP fault when formats `userdata` before install custom ROM...

Comment: Yeah you can check manually size of filesystem and partition to confirm. Or check logcat soon after encryption failure to see what exactly happened.

Comment: @IrfanLatif checking logcat on some custom ROMs can be difficult because not all have adb enabled during boot.

Comment: Activate `logcatd` service which saves persistent logs to `/data/misc/logd/`.

Answer (score 0):

I you would install a custom rom you can ask the maintainer of your rom, usually all custom roms from Android 5 and above Support it, nur maybe your device doesnt Support it in a custom rom. Normally the maintainer of your rom wrote a bug list in the XDA Thread, if that's too uncertain ask the maintainer.

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice but maintainer often doesn't respond for a question from users. Custom ROMs that I tried they have option to encrypt storage but it doesn't work. So that's why I'm looking for a more technical solution to check it.